# Will sqoop extract records present at initiation or will it sqoop records added to the table when the sqoop is running?

Tags: hive, sqoop

I have a table A that is constantly updated with new records. I am trying to sqoop the records from table A to HDFS at say 2:00 PM CT(source table A has 5M records) and the sqoop ends at 4:00 PM CT(table A has 5.5M records). My question is

- Will there be 5M records in the target or 5.5M?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_transaction_isolation), Sqoop uses the [read committed transaction isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Read_committed). So once the (one or more) `SELECT` queries that Sqoop performs underneath have been executed, the "selected" records will be the ones that are going to be inserted in Hive (I assume that you're importing data into Hive because of the tag you used in the question). So what determines the number of records that are going to be finally imported (5M or 5.5M records) is the execution of the `SELECT` queries, not the total amount of time that the whole import process takes.

Bear in mind that you can control the parallelism of the import process by specifying the number of mappers that are going to be used (parameter `--num-mappers`). Each mapper will perform an independent `SELECT` query.

Also, you can consider using [incremental imports](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_incremental_imports) in order to retrieve the new data that have been added to the database after the import process has finished. Besides, you can also use [free-form queries](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports) to have a finer grained control of the amount of data you want to import to your database.